# How to achieve vertical scrolling with scroll-snap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I would like to achieve vertical scrolling with a similar effect that is [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scroll-horizontally.html#secondPage) in section 2 and 3. I have a code that works very similarly (it's in the snippet at the end of the post) but I want to be able to scroll to the next section much earlier like in the first example I sent.
Also, I would like to use the scrolling in a page that has some content and then scroll to the full page slider. After finishing scrolling then carry on scrolling to the next sections without the snap-scroll effect.

I tried to remove `scroll-snap-align: start` from the first section but then it just goes directly to the next section.

```js
const gra = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
const init = function() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('section');
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].style.background = randomColor({
      luminosity: 'light'
    });
  }
  cssScrollSnapPolyfill()
}
init();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  font-size: calc(1rem + 3vw);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.js"></script>
<script src="https://bundle.run/css-scroll-snap-polyfill@0.1.2"></script>
<section>
  <h1>Section One</h1>
</section>
<section class='one'>
  <h1>Section Two</h1>
</section>
<section class='two'>
  <h1>Section Three</h1>
</section>
<section class='three'>
  <h1>Section Four</h1>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Section Five</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: can you add an mcve? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve